# BGInfo and WMI Filter

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller, wmi

I have applied a Logon script via GPO to run BGInfo. As I understand it, as I am setting a User Configuration the GPO must be applied to a User OU. We have an OU called SERVERS which is the only OU we want this GPO to run on, however when I linked the GPO to the SERVERS OU rather than the USERS OU, the GPO was not applied. As the GPO is therefore linked to the USERS OU, it runs on every PC/SERVER in our company - which is not what we want.

If my conclusions are correct so far, I presumed that the only way I could prevent the GPO from running on any OU other than SERVERS is via a WMI Filter, however I cannot seem to create a filter that will work because I cannot access a variable such as %computername%.

I would have thought I wanted a query such as:

```
gwmi -namespace root\directory\LDAP -query "select * from ds_computer where DS_cn = %computername% AND ds_distinguishedName like '%ou=servers%'"
```

This would be the equivalent of saying "SELECT * FROM ds_Computer where DS_cn = [Current COMPUTER BEING LOGGED ON TO] AND ds_distinguishedName like '%ou=servers%'"

But this of course will not evaluate.

Am I on the right track here? Or is there a better solution?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
dotdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want loopback processing. It runs "User Configuration" items assigned to a Computer's GPO as the user who logs in. So your GPO assigned to the Servers OU with configuration items for Users will run when the user logs in.

Microsoft has a better explanation in [Windows Server: Understand “User Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode”](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2548.windows-server-understand-user-group-policy-loopback-processing-mode.aspx)

Comment: +1 - It is technically possible to get the WMI filter to work but it would *painfully* slow to process vs. loopback.

Comment: Hi Chris - sounds like what I need. So, I would link the GPO to the Servers OU, NOT the Users OU. And then set loopback processing to either replace or merge?

Comment: Yeah. That's the meat of it.

Comment: You need to be aware that turning on loopback processing in a single GPO enables it for any other GPO that applies to that computer. Ensure there are no user settings in the GPO's that link to locations where these computer objects reside or you could see unexpected results. Test, test, test.

Comment: BTW, the reason the WMI method is horrible is because it performs an LDAP query for ALL computer objects in the domain and filters locally. Yikes!

Comment: @ChrisS - I have implemented your solution and it works very well. Some further testing is probably needed, but for now it works (famous last words). Charles - thanks for your input, noted!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid loopback processing; it is a troubleshooting *nightmare* and tends to come back and bite you sometimes years later. Instead use Group Policy Preferences (GPP) Item Level Targeting. The basic process is:

1. Create a new GPO
2. Browse to User Configuration | Preferences | Control Panel Settings | Schedules Tasks
3. Create a new Scheduled Task (At least Windows 7)
4. Configure your task to either run the script or directly launch your script
5. On the Triggers tab, create a trigger to start "At log on"

   1. As a bonus, you can have bginfo "update" periodically by setting the "Repeat task every" option
6. On the Common tab, check "Item-level Targeting" and open the Targeting dialog
7. Select New Item | Organizational Unit
8. Browse and select the OU to which you want to apply the GPP
9. Link the GPO to the location where your user objects are located

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I like the sound of this solution and will perhaps look at it next time -for now, I'll keep a bookmark of your suggestion. Thanks.